# Any recommended ftp benchmark?

Tags: centos, ftp

We have ftp server installed on linux (CentOS).

Can anybody recommend any linux based benchmark (especially with a lot of writes) which can test performance of this ftp server ?

Comment: Can't you just script you own? it'd be more realistic like that anyway?

Comment: In your script you could use something like [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/). Put lots of files of varying sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to find out what happens under load, try this in sh:

```
while true;
   do wget ftp://mysite.com/file;
done;
```

What exactly are you trying to benchmark? Download rates, or read/write rates? Your internet connection is almost certainly the bottleneck here, at least if your server hardware is anything remotely modern. If you're trying to benchmark your read/write rates to disk, then doing this test locally (run the program from the same server the FTP daemon is running on) will do the trick too.

Comment: You are right - doing this locally does the same.

Comment: Done this with your answer and pv : ` while true; do curl -s ftp://mysite.com/file; done | pv --line-mode --rate > /dev/null`